# python opens new console window instead of printing into cmd

Tags: python, python-3.x, powershell, windows-10

My Python 3 (3.6) opens new black console window for each Python command I run (`pip` is just the same).

Example: When I create a hello_world.py with a `while True: print("hello world")` Loop in it and start it from PowerShell via `python test.py` it will open a new window, print "hello world" in the new window and leave the console I used to run the script empty... (same happens with Cygwin) using CMD it won't even open the Python window and just closes gives me back a new CMD prompt-line.

Even worse when using PyCharm each time a background-task runs (e.g. syntax-check) a black console window opens for ~1 sec. and thus blocks me from writing code.

Example images to show what is happening:

*Code used for test.py:*

```
while True:
    print("Hello World")
```

[image: Example 1]

[image: Example 2]

So far I tried:

- creating and modifying manifest files for `python.exe`/`pythonw.exe`
- reinstalling Python3
- installing a different Python3 Version
- changing the default codepage for CMD/PowerShell
- setting `PYTHONENCODING` and `PYTHONIOENCODING` to UTF-8
- starting PowerShell/Python as admin

//edit:

the Question is: How can I get back the default Python behavior, as seen on every other (Windows) Computer.

Comment: What's the output for `where python`? And `where py`?

Comment: where python: D:\Python36\python.exe, where py: C:\Windows\py.exe

Comment: Does this also happen from `cmd.exe`? Ask on superuser.

Comment: This issue bugs me but feels like a Python bug in relation to using the PoweShell which is meant to replace the old DOS command-prompt. Running "py ./test.py" is a semi-fix but ideally whatever mechanism allows running "./test.py" needs to be aware it is being run from a shell instance instead of command-prompt. Is there a bug board for the python project?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution is just run cmd or powershell as Administrator any other type of user would cause this problem.